# matching python nested lists with (random variables)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, pattern-matching, match

I am doing some matching between strings.

```
t1 = '[go:VB, [like:IN, [i:PR]], [to:TO], [there:RB]]'
t2 = '[A, [like:IN, [B]], [to:TO], [C]]'
```

both t1 and t2 has the shape **X:Y**

which I call the

**X :** *word*

**Y :** *tag*

I would like to let

```
t1 == t2
```

in this example and this is can be done if we say something like:

```
for i in t1: 
    if i.tag in (‘NN’, ‘RB’, ‘JJ’,’ VB’, PN’):
        X:Y = #ANY ONE UPPER CASE VARIABLE
```

I **cannot** do it this way because they are **not lists** and I cannot do **(eval)** because of ( **:** ) which is **not accepted in lists**.

Wheat I did is that I *split* (‘ , ‘)

```
t1 = t1.split(',')
t2 = t2.split(',')
```

The new lists now is something like:

```
t1 = ['[go:VB', ' [like:IN', ' [i:PR]]', ' [to:TO]', ' [there:RB]]']
t2 = ['[A', ' [like:IN', ' [B]]', ' [to:TO]', ' [C]]']
```

now

```
t1[0] == t2[0]   #return FALSE
t1[1] == t2[1]   #return TRUE
t1[2] == t2[2]   #return FALSE
t1[3] == t2[3]   #return TRUE
t1[4] == t2[4]   #return FALSE
```

I need them all return *TRUE* even if I change the variable from ( A ) to any one capital case letter (e.g., Z, H, X)

I thought to take the last next to last member and what before it to select only the tag

```
>>> t1[0]
'[go:VB'
# to select only the tag
>>> t1[0][-2:]
'VB' # << This is what I want

>>> t1[1]
' [like:IN'
# to select only the tag
>>> t1[1][-2:]
'IN'  # << This is what I want

>>> t1[2]
' [i:PR]]'
# to select only the tag 
>>> t1[1][-2:]
']]'   # << This is NOT what I want
```

I do not know what to do here but there might be a useful thing to use, but I do not know how to fit it here

```
>>> t1[0][-2:].isalpha()
True
>>> t1[1][-2:].isalpha()
True
>>> t1[2][-2:].isalpha()
False
```

Comment: Sounds like your input data is in a really annoying format to work with. Did you create/do you maintain the function that generates the initial `t1` or `t2`? If so, that should be fixed first before this problem is even attempted.

Comment: t2 is imported from somebody else. t1 was nearly this but it used to have tuples and I removed them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick fix to your formatting problems -

```
import itertools
t1 = '[go:VB, [like:IN, [i:PR]], [to:TO], [there:RB]]'
t2 = '[A, [like:IN, [B]], [to:TO], [C]]'
t1=t1.replace("]","")
t1=t1.replace("[","")
t2=t2.replace("[","")
t2=t2.replace("]","")
t1=t1.split(",")
t2=t2.split(",")
print(t1)
print(t2)
for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(t1,t2):
    if i[-2:]==j[-2:]:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

The **output** for this is -

```
['go:VB', ' like:IN', ' i:PR', ' to:TO', ' there:RB']
['A', ' like:IN', ' B', ' to:TO', ' C']
false
true
false
true
false
```

However, I dont like this approach and I'll explain why.From parts of your code I can understand that you are working with sentences and **part of speech tagging(POS)**. I will address your problem by helping you generate a POS list that is actually readable. I employ **NLTK** module in python which is a powerful Natural Language processing tool **(trained on structured data)** You can find the documentation [here](http://www.nltk.org/)

```
import nltk
import itertools
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import *
text1= word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
text2= word_tokenize("And won for something completely same")
t1=nltk.pos_tag(text1)
t2=nltk.pos_tag(text2)
print(t1)
print(t2)

for i ,j in itertools.zip_longest( t1,t2 ):
    if i[1]==j[1]:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

And herein lies the **output.**

```
[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'), ('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
[('And', 'CC'), ('won', 'VBD'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'), ('completely', 'RB'), ('same', 'JJ')]
true
false
true
true
true
true
```

Pay close attention to the output, the reason for the last true is that they are both adjectives.Let me explain the code as simply as I can.Now as you can see, `word_tokenize()` is a method that breaks down the sentence into its respective tokens(try fooling around with words like "can't" and see what happens) and `pos_tag()` performs the POS tagging. This I'm sure you're aware of.**NOTE** - here, ":" is by default replaced with ",". Thus making it easier to differentiate between word and tag.This module not only helps you in this formatting it very powerful.You can train your data, extract entities and substantially improve the quality of your work.

However, noting that there exist variables in your sentence(which I would like to know where they arise from), I would suggest iterating over each item in the list and skipping the variables(as you want them to give a TRUE output anyway). Then, simply compare tags of the words between T1 and T2.

Comment: Well now that you've edited it seems like you only need the tags. Well then the easiest way to do it is to just take t1 and t2 and delete the recurring [ and ] brackets. Using split(",") makes your formatting only worse. So, remove the brackets and perform the same index search like you've used in your edit. It should work.

Comment: I did this and edited my answer. Tell me if it works for you. :)

Comment: So I read your other posts, it explains how t1 and t2 are fetched differently. I honestly feel this is all the more reason for you to stick to NLTK. You will not have this big of a headache removing tuples, creating unnecessary lists or fetching misformatted data. However do keep in mind that NLTK is appropriate for STRUCTURED DATA. If you are having troubles with NLTK ask more questions or try using spaCy API or Alchemy API. Again, these may be too powerful for your needs but they save you a great deal of headache.

Comment: You are right that I am using POS with each word in a sentence. But actually **t1** and **t2** are parsed trees, so I cannot delete ' [ '  and ' ] ' at all, so I am not looking for flatten the lists.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? You can still keep the parse trees and get the result. But flattening the lists is what you'll have to do. Its not elegant I realise. But you could just use NLTK and preferably fetch the POS tags at that level before you even get to parse trees.

Comment: in parsing [A, [B], [C]] != [A, B, C], so the sentence that I parse will lose its meaning if I remove the inner square brackets.

Comment: And am I right in assuming that each A, B, C is a chunk? For example, "this is paris, eiffel tower, tower of london" would probably chunk "eiffel tower" together. Is it a chunk? or something else?

Comment: I took each word separate , the parsing for "Eiffel tower" is something like '[tower:NN, [Eiffel:PN]]'. This is not like [tower, eiffel]

Comment: for x, y in zip(t1, t2):
        if x == y:
            return True:
        elif y[0][-2:] in (‘NN’, ‘JJ’, ‘VB’, ‘RB’, ‘PN’) 
            return True
        else: 
            return False

But I am not sure about **elif** here. because sometimes they are not an alphabet. so how can I check if they are not alpha then I go back one more step.

Comment: check for trailing "]]" with an if statement. If true then y[0][-4:]. Again, I've done all I can to help but this is extremely inefficient. You should REALLY try working with NLTK

Comment: I REALLY appreciate your help, and this discussion is very useful.  Thanks a lot